# Copy value from Excel cell to Word form field as currency format $xxx,xxx,xxx

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do I copy the value of an Excel cell to a Word form field in a currency format $xxx,xxx,xxx?

Value in Cell A1: `$200,000,000`

Code:

```vb
doc.FormFields(1).Result = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications

Comment: Did either of the Answers answer your question? If yes, could you please click the check mark next to the one that best matched. If not, please describe the current result you're seeing. Without knowing that it's difficult to analyze what the exact problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

When code is written like this it returns the default property of the object, in the case of a `Range` its value. Missing out the default property like this is not good practice. A change to the objects default property would break your code.

When working with ranges in Excel it is important to know the difference between the `Text` and `Value` properties. `Range("A1").Value` returns the value without the number formatting. `Range("A1").Text` will return the value with the number formatting. This is explained in the [Excel VBA reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.text)

Alternatively, if the form field is always supposed to hold a numeric value formatted as currency you should set the properties of the form field accordingly.

[image: Screenshot of the Text Form Fields Options dialog]

Answer (score 0):

This could be as simple as:

```
doc.FormFields(1).Result = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Text
```